# How align selected row like other row in uipickerview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I use custom label for uipickerview and use this code

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:     (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView   rowSizeForComponent:component].width - 20.0f, [pickerView   rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
    pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    if (component == 0) {
      pickerLabel.text = [aCAddWeightData.intValueWeights objectAtIndex:row];
      pickerLabel.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentRight;
    } else {
      pickerLabel.text = [aCAddWeightData.floatValueWeights objectAtIndex:row];
      pickerLabel.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
    return pickerLabel;
}
```

and i got it [image]

**I want align selected row and other row from vertical line, how i can do this?**

Answer (score 4):

As I see, this occurs only when we have 2 components and haven't set width for components. I found a workaround for this. Actually it's not clear why it works, but, when we set width for component value less than pickerView.frame.size.width/3 (in case when we've 2 components), we get selected row aligned as well as unselected rows.

```
// implement UIPickerViewDelegate's method
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 80;  // any value less than 106.6, assuming pickerView's width = 320
}
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html):

> You cannot customize the picker view’s selection indicator on iOS 7.

Edit: Try removing the .textAlignment properties altogether.

Comment: But in standart apple app picker [lool like] (http://www.danielsullivan.me/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/IMG_0204.png)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you wanted to change the appearance. Have you tried removing the .textAlignment properties?

Comment: I try, but it's not help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with any UIPickerView, customized or not.

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    CGFloat width = pickerView.frame.size.width;

    NSUInteger count = pickerView.numberOfComponents;
    //If count is wrong, use this instead:
    //NSUInteger count = yourDatasource.count;
    if(count > 1){
        width /= count;
    }

    return width;
}
```

And if you need alignment, it's in this method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UILabel* label = (UILabel*)view;

    if (!label){
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]];
        //Set here alignment depending on your component if needed
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }

    [label setText:@"Your text from your datasource"];

    return label;
}
```

Note: `UIPickerViewDelegate` of course.